# Cross Apply With Aggregates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Does a `CROSS APPLY` with an aggregate function return a row even there is no result in the inner expression?

I'm using Sql Server 2012.

Most of the times when I have a 
query that requires a derived table I usually use `CROSS APPLY`.
I think it's better performance wise, also, I have access to the outside 
table so I can perform TOP *n* for each row that gets joined etc.

Today I came across a very interesting behavior of cross apply 
which in my eyes it seems like a bug.

I was trying to do an aggregation on some table but I needed the 
details as well. so I wrote the query without any aggregation then, 
I tried a cross apply to sum up where the applied tables Id is equal
the id of the outer table.

As far I know, if the inner table is 
not returning anything then the outer table won't either (`CROSS 
APPLY` vs `OUTER APPLY`), and that's the case when I'm not using 
aggregates but when I use the `COUNT` function
I get back results even if the inner table doesn't return anything. I tried it 
with simple temp tables (see code) and surprisingly I got the same 
result.

If I do a `GROUP BY` it works fine.

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleParent (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, ParentName VARCHAR(25))

CREATE TABLE #SampleChildren (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, ParentId INT, ChildName VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO #SampleParent
(   ParentName )
VALUES ('Bob')

SELECT * 
FROM #SampleParent AS sp
CROSS APPLY (SELECT sc.ChildName FROM #SampleChildren AS sc WHERE sc.ParentId = sp.Id) c
WHERE sp.Id = 1

SELECT * 
FROM #SampleParent AS sp
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(sc.ChildName) c FROM #SampleChildren AS sc WHERE sc.ParentId = sp.Id) c
WHERE sp.Id = 1

--GROUP BY
SELECT * 
FROM #SampleParent AS sp
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(sc.ChildName) c FROM #SampleChildren AS sc WHERE sc.ParentId = sp.Id GROUP BY sc.ParentId) c
WHERE sp.Id = 1
```

So, the question is:

Does a `CROSS APPLY` with an aggregate function return a row even there is no result in the inner expression?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` will eliminate outer rows if the inner expression does not return a row.

An aggregate without a `GROUP BY` is a scalar aggregate (as opposed to vector aggregate) and (in the absence of a `HAVING` clause) always returns one row even if run against an empty table.

e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmptyTable` returns a single row with result `0` - not no rows.

So this explains the behaviour you are asking about.

Comment: wow! I didn't realized that. however, this is a big problem for me. when I do a group by it slows down the query dramatically. would you have any optimization idea for that?

Comment: @cohena you can add a `HAVING COUNT(sc.ChildName) > 0` to the scalar aggregate query so it returns 0 rows in the case it is 0. But I wouldnt write it anything like that anyway. I'd use `WHERE EXISTS`. E.g. `SELECT * 
FROM #SampleParent AS sp
WHERE sp.Id = 1 AND EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM #SampleChildren sc
WHERE sc.ParentId = sp.Id)`

Comment: WHERE EXISTS isn't a solution for me because it's not just a filter I need the actual count + some filters based on the inner query